# C# 6.0 Approach to Checking if Local Variable or Object is Null (not a field) Using the Null-propagation Operator

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I know with the new C# 6.0 you can check for null in the following simplified example:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
string example = myClass?.someFieldInMyClass;
```

This is a more concise way to check for nulls. Great!

I'm curious if there is a way to check if a local variable or parameter being passed in is null using the new operator. So if a parameter was passed to a method like so:

```
    public static void SomeMethod(mytype t) 
   {
       AnotherClass.myfield = t; 
   }
```

Is there a way to check if `t` is null? I've been looking around the documentation and haven't found anything.

I'm looking for something like `Anotherclass.somefield = ?t;`

Is the expectation that you would check it before passing it? The reason I want to do this is I am passing in a custom type, which is a property on another class. I am then setting the other class with the custom property I'm passing in.

Maybe this is just code smell, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reasoning. The primary goal of the null-propagating operator is to avoid `NullReferenceException` occurrences, but that wouldn't happen here. Are you saying you'd rather that line of code not fire when `t` is `null`? If that's the case, an `if` block would be preferable. To me, bearing the regular behavior of that operator in mind, I would expect `?t` to return `null`, which `t` already would.

Comment: What would You expect to happen if you get null? what should be result of `Anotherclass.somefield = ?t;` assignment?

Comment: It's not necessarily just to check if it's null. It's so it won't throw and assign the variable to null before it continues to an execution point that WILL throw. In your SomeMethod, you would just check if myfield is then null after the assignment.

Comment: What would you like happen if t is null and how is that different from simply assigning?

Comment: I think what @MatthewHaugen is saying is closest to this. I think I may have misunderstood the complete purpose of the `?` operator in this context. Or rather, misunderstood the intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you want to avoid overwriting the value of

```
AnotherClass.myfield
```

With a possible null t then you can just do this

```
AnotherClass.myfield = t ?? AnotherClass.myfield;
```

Then it will only change the assignment of myfield if t is NOT null, otherwise it will keep its previous assignment (reassign).

Comment: Nice. Although I think my original reasoning for asking the question was skewed, this is still a good answer and will be useful in my scenario.

Comment: @Jonesopolis I disagree in this case. Everyone who used c# for a few months will know what ?? does and it makes the code more readable over all. If there are if's all over the place I tend to lose clear view on what's happening.

Comment: null coalescing operator is neither new and supported is well supported in most languages, I've always found it very clear, this is assignment logic not control flow.

Comment: Personally, I'd still argue that any code that could result in `x = x` should strongly be reconsidered.  But I concede that this won't hurt anything if you're dead set on it.